# Generating dynamic backup tables script bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-composer

I have a task to create backup\copies of certain select tables from various datasets from one project into another (or) within the same project. A model query is listed below. There are about 300 odd tables in total.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE $target_project.$target_dataset.$table_name_$suffix AS
SELECT * FROM $source_project.$source_dataset.$table_name
```

In order to accomplish this, I have created a config table with the dataset name and table name. I have two approaches in mind -

Option 1 -
Create SQL script which loops through all the records from the config table, generates dynamic sql and executes them. Am unable to find a proper way to loop through table records, getting values in variables. The struct command only takes one query at a time.

Option 2 -
Create a sql file containing all the CREATE TABLE SCRIPT statements with placeholders for the project name and suffix names.
Use a DAG, pass the variables into the sql file and execute the script using Cloud Composer.

Option 2 is working and feasible. It is just not scalable owing the fact that any changes to be made would require one to modify the script again, re-upload etc.

Can someone help me with Option 1 (or) advise if there is any better way to accomplish this task?

We work with the gcp suite of products and am happy to engage with various tools to accomplish this.

Comment: You should be able to loop inside a stored procedure as it allows variable declaration. So, you can create a stored procedure with all your looping logic and try to generate dynamic sqls you intend to.

FOR record IN
  (SELECT word, word_count
   FROM bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare
   LIMIT 5)
DO
  SELECT record.word, record.word_count;
END FOR;

The above example statement, if you use in a stored procedure it should help.

Comment: You can use option 1. Share your code to let us understand what you did wrong

Comment: are you using google cloud composer? do you want an example of a dag for that? would need a sample of your code if you are still looking for an answer